# homology connectedness and open sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let's make the following recursive definition.
We will say a topological space $X$ is

- $(-1)$-connected if it is not the empty set
- $n$-connected if it is $n-1$-connected and not the union of two $n-1$-connected open sets $U,V$ for which $U \cap V$ is not $n-1$-connected.

Is being $n$-connected the same as having $\tilde H_0, \dots, \tilde H_n$ be trivial? If not, what's a counterexample?

Comment: No. Being $0$-connected is the same as being connected. Having trivial $\tilde H_0$ is the same as being pathwise connected, which is stronger.

Comment: So you probably want to restrict to $X$ locally path connected, or some generalization of that for higher $n$. In any case, what have you tried?

Comment: Your comment is clear enough to be an answer @Tzimmo.

Comment: To the OP, you might wish to avoid downvotes by adding a little bit of [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), perhaps in the form of some kind of motivation, or some kind of partial attempt.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for the advice, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: It would be interesting if we slightly modify the definition and define $0$-connected to mean (nonempty) path connected.

Comment: Note that "$n$-connected" has a standard meaning (e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-connected+space) which doesn't line up with this.

Comment: Hi guys! Sorry about the wording, I should have called it something other than n-connected. And yeah, connected =/= path-connected is a good point- maybe we can restrict to CW complexes. In that case, is the statement true?

Answer (score 3):

Being $n$-connected is not the same as having trivial cohomology groups $\tilde H_i$ for $i \leq n$. The definition of being $0$-connected is identical to the usual definition of a connected topological space. Having trivial $\tilde H_0$, however, is equivalent to the space being pathwise connected. This is a stronger condition than being connected.

Thus, any connected topological space that is not pathwise connected is a counterexample. A famous example of such a space is the [Topologist's Sine Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

Comment: What would happen if we restricted our attention to CW complexes? Thanks!

Comment: That is a very different question. It might be worth posting this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to define $n$-connected from the point set point of view, you can consider the standard definition from basic homotopy theory:

A non-empty space $X$ is $n$-connected for $n\geq 0$ if $\pi_d(X)=0$ for $0\leq d\leq n$.

The condition for $d=0$ requires that $X$ be path connected.

Then for $n\geq2$, the Hurewicz Theorem states that if $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected, that the reduced homology is also $0$ through dimension $n-1$ and that the Hurewicz homomorphism is an isomorphism in dimension $n$ ($n=1$ a special case that is slightly different).

$h_*:\pi_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(X)$

Comment: I think this definition is great, but I was just wondering if there's also a weird point set interpretation of connectedness. (also thanks for reminding me, I need to learn more about the Hurewicz theorem!)